# $_REQUEST['country'] doesn't work

Tags: php, input, request

If I use the instruction die($_REQUEST['country']); report this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\cart.php on line 198
```

This happens only with the second conditional, the first conditional works perfectly and get the country:

```
<?php } elseif(@is_numeric($_SESSION['user_registered_id'])) { ?>
      <input name="country" type="text" disabled id="pais" value="<?=$qpais?>" size="1" readonly />
      <?php } ?> <-//this fails
```

This is the complete code:

```
//This if works perfectly
<?php if (!@is_numeric($_SESSION['user_registered_id'])){?>
              <select name="country" id="pais">                      
                 <option value="ESP" selected>España (ESP)</option>
               <?php foreach($countries_list as $key => $value){?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $key?>"><?php echo $value['name']. ' ('.$key.')';?></option>
                       <?php } ?>
   //This fails                    
  <?php } elseif(@is_numeric($_SESSION['user_registered_id'])) { ?>
                           <input name="country" type="text" disabled id="pais" value="<?=$qpais?>" size="1" readonly />
                   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Start debugging, check if it actually gets to the elseif. With by example echoing a sentence.

Comment: why are you using the error suppressing "@" for "is_numeric"?

Comment: Where is the rest of the form tags?

Comment: And to extend Daniele's question, why wouldn't it be numeric? If this is a way of checking that it exists, surely empty() or isset() would be more appropriate.

Comment: Holla amigo! have you started the session?

Comment: Why do you have disabled attribute on input? It is probably key to your problem. Disabled elements are not sended.

Comment: @kbarborak is right, disabled fields do not get submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to disable attribute in input box, Please make only readonly="readonly" attribute so it can get value in second page. please refer code below

```
<input name="country" type="text" id="pais" value="<?=$qpais?>" size="1" readonly="readonly" />
```